# Is there a Super Soul similar to this Z-Soul? (KO = Max Ki)

Tags: dragon-ball-xenoverse-2

In the original DBZ Xenoverse, there was a Z-Soul called "[Why yoooou!!!](http://dbxenoverse.wikia.com/wiki/Z-Soul)" whitch activates when you KO an enemy. When it activates, you get MAX KI in return.

Is there a Super Soul like that in DBZ Xenoverse 2?

Comment: Please try using coherent sentences...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah its called "I hope you're reborn as someone good this time." It says it completely restores health when you KO someone but the text is incorrect and it actually restores all your KI